# In a QLikView script generate code dependent of parameters in function call

Tags: code-generation, qlikview

I have a script in QLikView to extract and check my data. It has to perform a data extraction for 12 separate times. I made a function that works properly but some things are hardcoded and I want to call the same function 12 times with different parameters. The question that I have is about code generation dependent of the parameters in the function.

A part of my code is :

```
SUB SplitsenOpMiddel(middel, eersteVraag, laatsteVraag)

Temp_Middel_$(middel):
LOAD
    Veldzoeknaam                                AS ZoekNaam,
    VeldP_id                                    AS $(middel)_VeldP_id,
    Middel                                      AS $(middel)_Middel,
    MATEnr                                      AS $(middel)_MATE,
    IF(Vraagnr=1, VeldWaarde)                   AS $(middel)_Vraag001,
    IF(Vraagnr=2, VeldWaarde)                   AS $(middel)_Vraag002,
    IF(Vraagnr=3, VeldWaarde)                   AS $(middel)_Vraag003,
    IF(Vraagnr=4, VeldWaarde)                   AS $(middel)_Vraag004,
    IF(Vraagnr=5, VeldWaarde)                   AS $(middel)_Vraag005,
    IF(Vraagnr=6, VeldWaarde)                   AS $(middel)_Vraag006,
    IF(Vraagnr=1, VeldTypeGrp)                  AS $(middel)_Vraag001Type,
    IF(Vraagnr=2, VeldTypeGrp)                  AS $(middel)_Vraag002Type,
    IF(Vraagnr=3, VeldTypeGrp)                  AS $(middel)_Vraag003Type,
    IF(Vraagnr=4, VeldTypeGrp)                  AS $(middel)_Vraag004Type,
    IF(Vraagnr=5, VeldTypeGrp)                  AS $(middel)_Vraag005Type,
    IF(Vraagnr=6, VeldTypeGrp)                  AS $(middel)_Vraag006Type

RESIDENT Data2
WHERE Vraagsort = '$(middel)';
```

In this case, the function call is :

```
CALL SplitsenOpMiddel('A', 1, 6)
```

So far, the numbers 1 to 6 are hardcoded but what I want is generate this code dependent of the second and third parameter.

My second function call will be :

```
CALL SplitsenOpMiddel('B', 7, 10)
```

And automatically the code needs to be :

```
Temp_Middel_$(middel):
LOAD
    Veldzoeknaam                                AS ZoekNaam,
    VeldP_id                                    AS $(middel)_VeldP_id,
    Middel                                      AS $(middel)_Middel,
    MATEnr                                      AS $(middel)_MATE,
    IF(Vraagnr=7, VeldWaarde)                   AS $(middel)_Vraag007,
    IF(Vraagnr=8, VeldWaarde)                   AS $(middel)_Vraag008,
    IF(Vraagnr=9, VeldWaarde)                   AS $(middel)_Vraag009,
    IF(Vraagnr=10, VeldWaarde)                  AS $(middel)_Vraag010,
    IF(Vraagnr=7, VeldTypeGrp)                  AS $(middel)_Vraag007Type,
    IF(Vraagnr=8, VeldTypeGrp)                  AS $(middel)_Vraag008Type,
    IF(Vraagnr=9, VeldTypeGrp)                  AS $(middel)_Vraag009Type,
    IF(Vraagnr=10, VeldTypeGrp)                 AS $(middel)_Vraag0010Type

RESIDENT Data2
WHERE Vraagsort = '$(middel)';
```

Is there a way in QlikView to perform this?

Another part of my code where I need the same type of code generation is :

```
Check_Middel_$(middel):
NOCONCATENATE LOAD
    ZoekNaam,
    $(middel)_VeldP_id,
    $(middel)_Middel,
    $(middel)_MATE,

    IF(ISNULL($(middel)_Vraag001), 
    IF(ISNULL($(middel)_Vraag002) AND
        ISNULL($(middel)_Vraag003) AND
        ISNULL($(middel)_Vraag004) AND
        ISNULL($(middel)_Vraag005) AND
        ISNULL($(middel)_Vraag006), 'G', 'F'))
                                                AS $(middel)_Leeg_Check,

    IF($(middel)_Vraag001 = 0,
    IF($(middel)_Vraag002 = 0 AND
    $(middel)_Vraag003 = 0 AND
    $(middel)_Vraag004 = 0 AND
    $(middel)_Vraag005 = 0 AND
    $(middel)_Vraag006 = 0, 'G', 'F'))
                                                AS $(middel)_0_Check,

    IF(($(middel)_Vraag001 <> 0 AND NOT ISNULL($(middel)_Vraag001)), 
    IF(ISNULL($(middel)_Vraag002) OR
       ISNULL($(middel)_Vraag003) OR
       ISNULL($(middel)_Vraag004) OR
       ISNULL($(middel)_Vraag005) OR
       ISNULL($(middel)_Vraag006), 'F',
    IF(($(middel)_Vraag002 = 0) AND ($(middel)_Vraag003 = 0) AND ($(middel)_Vraag004 = 0) AND ($(middel)_Vraag005 = 0) AND ($(middel)_Vraag006 = 0), 'M', 'G')))
                                                AS $(middel)_Vol_Check,

    $(middel)_Vraag001,
    $(middel)_Vraag002,
    $(middel)_Vraag003,
    $(middel)_Vraag004,
    $(middel)_Vraag005,
    $(middel)_Vraag006
RESIDENT Middel_$(middel);

DROP TABLE Middel_$(middel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "build" the script on the fly. The code below shows how this can be achieved for the first function `SplitsenOpMiddel` can look. Calling this function like this     `call SplitsenOpMiddel('A', 1, 6)` will generate the table with the required fields.

You can have a look at the sample qvw [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dFwHdsss37geex6DyeJiuTNKVuhq7L0t). Tried to cover both cases but might not work as you expected but will give you an idea.

```
sub SplitsenOpMiddel(middel, eersteVraag, laatsteVraag)

  let Temp_Middel = 'Temp_Middel_' & '$(middel)' & ':' & chr(13) & 'Load' & chr(13);

  for b = $(eersteVraag) to $(laatsteVraag)
      let Temp_Middel = '$(Temp_Middel)' & 'IF(Vraagnr=' & $(b) & ', VeldWaarde) AS' & ' $(middel)' & '_Vraag00' & $(b) & ',' & chr(13) & 
                        'IF(Vraagnr=' & $(b) & ', VeldTypeGrp) AS' & ' $(middel)' & '_Vraag00' & $(b) & 'Type,' &  chr(13);  
  next

  let Temp_Middel = '$(Temp_Middel)' & 'Veldzoeknaam AS ZoekNaam,' & chr(13) & 
                    'VeldP_id AS ' & '$(middel)' & '_VeldP_id,' & chr(13) & 
                    'Middel AS ' & '$(middel)'& '_Middel,' & chr(13) & 
                    'MATEnr AS ' & '$(middel)' & '_MATE ' & chr(13) & 
                    'Resident Data2' & chr(13) & 
                    'WHERE Vraagsort =' & chr(39) & '$(middel)' & chr(39) & ';';  

  $(Temp_Middel);
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is if it could work, I would answer yes. Variables in QlikView are handled as text to be replaced when invoked, so I see to reason why it shouldn't work.